# Spark Yarn Architecture

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

[image]

I had a question regarding this image in a tutorial I was following. So based on this image in a yarn based architecture does the execution of a spark application look something like this:

First you have a driver which is running on a client node or some data node. In this driver (similar to a driver in java?) consists of your code (written in java, python, scala, etc.) that you submit to the Spark Context. Then that spark context represents the connection to HDFS and submits your request to the Resource manager in the Hadoop ecosystem. Then the resource manager communicates with the Name node to figure out which data nodes in the cluster contain the information the client node asked for. The spark context will also put a executor on the worker node that will run the tasks. Then the node manager will start the executor which will run the tasks given to it by the Spark Context and will return back the data the client asked for from the HDFS to the driver.

Is the above interpretation correct?

Also would a driver send out three executors to each data node to retrieve the data from the HDFS, since the data in HDFS is replicated 3 times on various data nodes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your interpretation is close to reality but it seems that you are a bit confused on some points.

Let's see if I can make this more clear to you.

Let's say that you have the word count example in Scala.

```
object WordCount {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      val inputFile = args(0)
      val outputFile = args(1)
      val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount")

      val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

      val input =  sc.textFile(inputFile)

      val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))

      val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}

      counts.saveAsTextFile(outputFile)
    }
}
```

In every spark job you have an initialisation step where you create a SparkContext object providing some configuration like the appname and the master, then you read a inputFile, you process it and you save the result of your processing on disk. All this code is running in the Driver except for the anonymous functions that make the actual processing (functions passed to .flatMap, .map and reduceByKey) and the I/O functions textFile and saveAsTextFile which are running remotely on the cluster.

Here the DRIVER is the name that is given to that part of the program running locally on the same node where you submit your code with [spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) (in your picture is called Client Node). You can submit your code from any machine (either ClientNode, WorderNode or even MasterNode) as long as you have spark-submit and network access to your YARN cluster. For simplicity I will assume that the Client node is your laptop and the Yarn cluster is made of remote machines.

For simplicity I will leave out of this picture Zookeeper since it is used to provide High availability to HDFS and it is not involved in running a spark application. I have to mention that Yarn Resource Manager and HDFS Namenode are roles in Yarn and HDFS (actually they are processes running inside a JVM) and they could live on the same master node or on separate machines. Even Yarn Node managers and Data Nodes are only roles but they usually live on the same machine to provide data locality (processing close to where data are stored).

When you submit your application you first contact the Resource Manager that together with the NameNode try to find Worker nodes available where to run your spark tasks. In order to take advantage of the data locality principle, the Resource Manager will prefer worker nodes that stores on the same machine HDFS blocks (any of the 3 replicas for each block) for the file that you have to process. If no worker nodes with those blocks is available it will use any other worker node. In this case since data will not be available locally, HDFS blocks has to be moved over the network from any of the Data nodes to the node manager running the spark task. This process is done for each block that made your file, so some blocks could be found locally, some have to moved.

When the ResourceManager find a worker node available it will contact the NodeManager on that node and ask it to create an a Yarn Container (JVM) where to run a spark executor. In other cluster modes (Mesos or Standalone) you won't have a Yarn container but the concept of spark executor is the same. A spark executor is running as a JVM and can run multiple tasks.

The Driver running on the client node and the tasks running on spark executors keep communicating in order to run your job. If the driver is running on your laptop and your laptop crash, you will loose the connection to the tasks and your job will fail. That is why when spark is running in a Yarn cluster you can specify if you want to run your driver on your laptop "--deploy-mode=client" or on the yarn cluster as another yarn container "--deploy-mode=cluster". For more details look at [spark-submit](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation!! In regards to how the Resource manager and name node work together to find a worker node. So basically the three replicas of your file are stored on three different data nodes in HDFS. The Resource manager will select the worker node that has the first HDFS block based on data locality and contact the NodeManager on that worker node to create a Yarn Container (JVM) on where to run a spark executor. If the other blocks are not available in this "range", then it will go to the other worker nodes and transfer the other blocks over

Comment: the network to the closest data node the resource manager found originally (with that spark executor running on) correct?

Comment: Also regarding your input file in the sample word count program you wrote above is that coming from HDFS?

Comment: In order to explain my example I assumed that it was coming from hdfs, but the same source code will work both for local files and hdfs files. If you use spark-submit, spark will assume the input file path is relative to hdfs, if you run it in Intellij idea as Java program it will assume it is a local file. You can even use hdfs file if running from Intellij but in that case you have to specify hdfs://<path>. In this last case you will loose locality since you are running on your laptop and reading from remote hdfs cluster

Comment: Ohh now this makes sense, Awesome! Thanks for all the clarifications, Definitely helped a lot!

Comment: Hey PinoSan I know this might be a little late but when the client submits a job won't it first communicate with the NameNode (in HDFS) which contains the metadata of where to find the file in the data nodes in a cluster. Then when the job gets submitted to the data node, the NodeManager for that DataNode will communicate with the ResourceManager (which is on the same machine as the NameNode in this case) to allocate resources and create a Yarn Container to start the spark executor which will run the spark tasks.