# Are the data nodes in an HDFS the same as the executor nodes in a spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am learning about Apache Spark and HDFS. I understand both of them for the most part although I am confused about one thing. My question is: Are the data nodes in the HDFS the same as the executor nodes in a spark cluster? In other words, are the nodes in the HDFS operating on the data that they contain or is the data from the datanodes in the HDFS sent to executors nodes in a spark cluster where the data is operated on? Please let me know if you would like me to clarify anything! Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you,

Taylor

Answer (score 2):

I always think those concepts from a standalone perspective firstly, then to a cluster perspective.

Considering a single machine (and you will also run Spark in local mode), `DataNode` and `NameNode` are just **pieces of software** to support HDFS abstract design (that is `NameNode` stores file trees, file metadata etc, while `DataNode` stores actual data chunks.). `driver` and `executors` are concepts in Spark, in local mode, a Spark application consist of a `driver` **process** and a set of `executor` **process** , which run as **threads** on your individual computer.

Answer (score 2):

Only if the DataNode is also running a NodeManager.  HDFS only handles data.  YARN handles compute.  YARN's ResourceManager assigns compute resources to NodeManagers which for obvious reasons are co-located with DataNodes.

YARN and Spark attempt to move executors to the DataNodes/NodeManagers which have the data Spark is processing (data-locality) but this is more an optimization and not a hard requirement.  Especially since most modern data centers have 10GB Ethernet backplanes so the cost of moving the data to a spare node is less costly than before where moving data across the network was expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If your Spark cluster is running with a master of `yarn`, then yes, your Spark executors will be running on the same nodes in the Hadoop cluster that store data.

In fact, moving the computation to the data, instead of the data to the computation, is a key method of improving performance in a distributed computation, as moving a serialised task to a node is a lot cheaper than moving GBs of data to the task.

Comment: DataNodes don't handle compute.  NodeManagers do.

Answer (score 0):

There is master node and numerous worker nodes.
Master node has HDFS Name Node which is like a directory service which maintains location of data blocks where a file is located. It also has YARN Resource Manager. These should be configured for automatic restart if they crash.
Data nodes are separate JVMs. On one worker node (VM or physical machine), you can have one or more data nodes (for high availability etc). Each data node is a JVM which does not need much CPU.
Then the worker nodes have Node Manager which is part of YARN. This is also a JVM. One per node is sufficient.
Finally, when you submit Spark application, it is submitted to YARN resource manager. It creates an Application Master which is a JVM and a YARN component on one of the worker nodes. Same JVM doubles up as Spark cluster manager also. Node managers create Spark executor JVMs, which coordinate with Spark cluster manager running in same process as YARN Application Master.
Here is an image I copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36215672/spark-yarn-architecture)!

[image: YARN with Spark Layout]